# How To Remove Black Bars from Videos using VLC Control C#

Tags: c#, vlc, vlc.dotnet

I have created vlcControl added on my windows form. I would like to know how can get rid of black bars on my vlc videos (image consumes black space). An example is shown below:
[image]

I have tried the line `vlc --aspect-ratio 16:9 -L -f /directory/to/file/filename`. 
The line changes the aspect ratio but did not work as expected. I have tried the following lines of code:

Line 1:

```
vlcCustomer.Play(new Uri("rtsp://192.168.1.10/2/media/video1"), ":network-caching=50 :aspect-ratio=16:9 -L -f /directory/to/file/filename");
```

Line 2:

```
vlcCustomer.Play(new Uri("rtsp://192.168.1.10/2/media/video1"), ":network-caching=50 vlc --aspect-ratio 16:9 -L -f /directory/to/file/filename");
```

Comment: do you want to stretch the image? cut off the sides? or shrink your window?

Comment: If the parameters are separated with `:` I wonder how it will parse that aspect ratio with the exact same character.

Comment: @DenisSchaf, Yes. I want my image to consume all the black space.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use CLI args for this, libvlc has an API for changing aspect ratio and it is available in Vlc.DotNet. Example: https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/blob/f0d3e2aca37500ccd2710c8b9b286ccc485f1636/src/Samples/Samples.WinForms.Advanced/Sample.cs#L167

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your control will have the same size, whatever the aspect ratio you give to it, and it will need to fill with black bars. to get rid of it, you will need to resize your control and center it based on the aspect ratio you can get from the media info.

Answer (score 0):

## Modify this code according to your screen and paste after your code:

```
VideoWidth = "1280";
VideoHeight = "750";
VlcControl2.Video.AspectRatio = VideoWidth + ":" + VideoHeight;
```